# How to apply a function in an "IN" clause

Tags: sql, oracle, business-objects

I have a list of values that returns values in this format: "NAME - ID". In the Universe, I need to do a join between my tables and the values the user choose, but my problem is that in my table only exists the ID column.

I'm able to do this:

```
select  t.column1, t.column2, ...
from    my_table t
where   t.id in regexp_substr(@prompt('1. Choose an element:', 'C', 'Elements\Identifiers',
                               Mono, Free, not_persistent, ), '*[[:digit:]]+$')
```

With the regular expression, I get the numeric part of the identifier and the "join" works fine, but now I need to allow multiple selection. So, my question is: is there a way to apply the `regexp_substr` to every value returned by prompt?

SQL Translation: (Is there a way to do this?)

```
select  t.column1, t.column2, ...
from    my_table t
where   t.id in regexp_substr(('FOO - 123', 'BAR - 456', 'ZOO - 789'),  '*[[:digit:]]+$')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would do this with `in`, unless you use a recursive CTE.  But the following logic might work:

```
where @prompt('1. Choose an element:', 'C', 'Elements\Identifiers', Mono, Free, not_persistent
             ) like '%- ' || t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change `Mono` to `Multi` in your `@Prompt` definition, you should be able to select or enter multiple values. The selected values will then be returned as a comma separated list, just like for an `IN` clause.

Thus, your SQL statement would then be:

```
select  t.column1, t.column2, ...
from    my_table t
where   t.id in regexp_substr(@prompt('1. Choose an element:', 'C', 'Elements\Identifiers', Multi, Free, not_persistent, ), '*[[:digit:]]+$')
```